# fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc6.h: No such file or directory #include gcc_header(__GNUC__) ^

Tags: android, c, linux, gcc, kernel

I'm trying to compile android-kernel-goldfish-2-6-29 but when i use make -j2 to compile it, i get this error:

`include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:86:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc6.h: No 
 such file or directory
 #include gcc_header(__GNUC__)`

my ubuntu is 17.04 and i downgrade my gcc to

`gcc version 4.7.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu12)`

can any body fix the problem?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275515/linux-compiler-gcc5-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and [this](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/2762)

Comment: @Gaurav Pathak, these links didn't say complete answer!

Comment: Is there `ERROR_ON_WARNING` in your `Makefile`? Have you tried setting it to NO?

Comment: @GauravPathak no there isn't `ERROR_ON_WARNING`  in Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the goldfish version from 2.6.29 to 3.18 and now everything is okay.